# Disable Backlight Timeout in BlackBerry devices

Tags: java, blackberry

I'm trying to disable the Backlight Timeout function on BlackBerry device - where the screen automatically dims after a period of inactivity.

The only thing I can do at this moment is go to:
**Options** -> **Display** -> **Screen Components** -> **Backlight Timeout**
and change the time there.  The default is 10 seconds and the maximum is 2 minutes.

Does anyone know how to completely disable this Backlight Timeout function with Java code?

Comment: I guess the answer is on this post: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Enable-the-backlight-and-prevent-the-BlackBerry-device-screen/ta-p/444706

Comment: You should make that comment an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found [the answer](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Enable-the-backlight-and-prevent-the-BlackBerry-device-screen/ta-p/444706).

Answer (score 4):

to prevent turn off screen for longer than 255 seconds: create TimerTask that enable backlight every 255, and then schedule it using timer:

```
  class BacklightTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        Backlight.enable(true, 255);
    }
  }
```

schedule task

```
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new BacklightTimerTask(), 5000, 5000);
```